# filter multiple lines based on one value

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects

in my BO

I have a table with:

```
OrderID | order Number | reason code 
123     | a            | r2
123     | b            | r1
123     | c            | r3
124     |d             | r3
```

I'm using same source for 2 sheets and on one I need all OrderID's where i Have reason R2 for at least one line

and on another all the rest
so need to one should have only:

```
OrderID | order Number | reason code 
123     | a            | r2
123     | b            | r1
123     | c            | r3
```

and second sheet should only have:

```
OrderID | order Number | reason code 
124     |d             | r3
```

I can add that order numbers are unique so cant have 2 of the same numbers in different orders... if it makes any difference.??

Comment: Something seems to be missing...or this is simpler than it seems.  it seems like all you are doing is splitting the results based on OrderID.  Can you provide more detail?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

*1st sheet -*

```
;with test_data(order_id, order_number, reason_code) as (
    select 123, 'a', 'r2' union all
    select 123, 'b', 'r1' union all
    select 123, 'c', 'r3' union all
    select 124, 'd', 'r3' 
)
--
-- Test data above; Desired query below
--
select *
from test_data a
where exists (
    select 1 from test_data b
    where   a.order_id = b.order_id
            and b.reason_code = 'r2'
)
```

Output:

```
   123   a  r2
   123   b  r1
   123   c  r3
```

*2nd sheet -*

```
;with test_data(order_id, order_number, reason_code) as (
    select 123, 'a', 'r2' union all
    select 123, 'b', 'r1' union all
    select 123, 'c', 'r3' union all
    select 124, 'd', 'r3' 
)
--
-- Test data above; Desired query below
--
select *
from test_data a
where NOT exists (
    select 1 from test_data b
    where   a.order_id = b.order_id
            and b.reason_code = 'r2'
)
```

Output:

```
124  d  r3
```

Hope this helps. Please revert.